# AWS SAM: Unable to unmarshal input

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sam

I'm trying to build a lambda function with SAM (python3.8).
I installed the AWS toolkit on VSCode and created the hello_world function.
SAM Build completed successfully.
When I run the *invoke* command with the predefined test/events/event.json I get an exception:

```sh
sam local invoke "TestFunction" -e test/events/event.json
```

the output:

```sh
{"errorMessage": "Unable to unmarshal input: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", "errorType": "Runtime.UnmarshalError", "stackTrace": []}
```

When running without an event, the function doesn't raise any errors.

versions:

- SAM CLI, version 1.23.0
- aws-cli/1.18.69 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.8.0-53-generic botocore/1.16.19
- Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289

Can you guide me on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the content of your event file test/events/event.json, will make it easier to debug the issue

Answer (score 2):

You should provide your Python code to see what the issue really is.
But I guess the problem is with `requests.post` call.

Instead of:

```py
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json_data)
```

try:

```py
requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data)
# Or
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(json_data))
```